# Link against CoreTelephony Framework (iOS)

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, ios5, core-telephony

Does anyone know why I get a linker error when I try to compile the following code:

```
extern void * _CTServerConnectionCreate(CFAllocatorRef, int (*)(void *, CFStringRef, CFDictionaryRef, void *), int *);

int callback(void *connection, CFStringRef string, CFDictionaryRef dictionary, void *data) 
{
    return 0;
}

%hook UIKeyboard

-(id)hitTest:(CGPoint)test withEvent:(id)event
{
    int x = 0;
    _CTServerConnectionCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, callback, &x);
    return %orig;
}

%end
```

**make** output is:

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv6:
>     "*CTServerConnectionCreate(*_CFAllocator const*, int (*)(void*, __CFString const*, __CFDictionary const*, void*), int*)", referenced from:
>         $_ungrouped$UIKeyboard$hitTest$withEvent$(UIKeyboard*, objc_selector*, CGPoint, objc_object*)      in Tweak.xm.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv6
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Some NOTES:

- I link against CoreTelephony with **-framework CoreTelephony**
- I use the code from here [Core Telephony Example](http://iflickr.googlecode.com/svn/wiki/LocationAwarenessoniPhone.wiki)
- I tried it on both iOS 4.x and iOS 5.x
- I used **nm** to ensure that the function call is inside the binary

And yes I'm on a jailbroken device.

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just include CoreTelephony.framework in XCode. Should work!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to declare your private function without the underscore.

```
 extern void *CTServerConnectionCreate();

// Call
myRes = CTServerConnectionCreate(args);
```

The compiler will automatically add the underscore prefix.